# change style by defaut on li

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I change by default **margin-bottom:0px** -> **margin-bottom:60px** on **li** balise ?

I add **margin-bottom:60px** in **style** for **li.feed-item** but nothing change. Someone have an idea, my goal is to **add margin-bottom:60px to all li balise**

here is my page: http://500milligrammes.com/fmzz/final/test/

and here is my style:

```
<style  type="text/css">
body { background: #f1f1f0; color: #282828; font-size:11px; font-family:"pt_sans_captionregular", sans-serif;}
a img { border:15px solid #fff}




.juicer-feed.image-grid li.feed-item, .juicer-feed.slider li.feed-item, .juicer-feed.hip li.feed-item { background:#f1f1f0;}

.juicer-feed.image-grid .text .message a, .juicer-feed.slider .text .message a, .juicer-feed.hip .text .message a { color:#f1f1f0; }

.juicer-feed.image-grid .text .message a, .juicer-feed.slider .text .message a, .juicer-feed.hip .text .message a:hover { color:#e0ccb4; }

.post-overlay.juicer-feed a.juicer-button { color:#e0ccb4; border: 1px solid #e0ccb4;}

.post-overlay.juicer-feed a.juicer-button:hover { color:#e0ccb4; border: 1px solid #e0ccb4; background:none;}
.j-loading { border: 4px solid #e0ccb4; }
.j-paginate.juicer-button.fart:hover { background: #e0ccb4; }
.j-loading::before { background-color:#e0ccb4; }

.juicer-feed .j-meta a:hover { color:#e0ccb4; }

.juicer-feed .j-paginate { border: 2px solid #e0ccb4; color:#e0ccb4; }

.juicer-feed .j-meta li, .post-overlay.juicer-feed ul.j-share li  { display: inline; }

.post-overlay.juicer-feed .j-overlay-text { background:#f1f1f0; }

ul.j-share li { margin:0; padding:0; }

.juicer-feed,  { background: #fff; }

.post-overlay.juicer-feed .j-overlay-text, .post-overlay.juicer-feed .j-overlay-text { background: #f1f1f0; }

.juicer-feed.image-grid .j-meta, .juicer-feed.slider .j-meta, .juicer-feed.hip .j-meta { position: absolute; bottom: 20px; width: 90%; text-align: left; padding:0; margin:0; }

.juicer-feed.image-grid .j-text, .juicer-feed.slider .j-text, .juicer-feed.hip .j-text { background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9); }


p, .juicer-feed.image-grid .j-text .message p, .juicer-feed.slider .j-text .message p, .juicer-feed.hip .j-text .message p { color: #282828; font-size:12px; font-family:"pt_sans_captionregular", sans-serif;}

.juicer-feed.image-grid .j-text, .juicer-feed.slider .j-text, .juicer-feed.hip .j-text { color: #282828; }


.juicer-feed.image-grid .j-text .message a, .juicer-feed.slider .j-text .message a, .juicer-feed.hip .j-text .message a { color: #282828; }

.juicer-feed.image-grid .j-text .message a:hover, .juicer-feed.slider .j-text .message a:hover, .juicer-feed.hip .j-text .message a:hover { color: #e0ccb4; }

.juicer-feed .j-meta a { color: #282828; }
.juicer-feed .j-meta a:hover { color: #e0ccb4; }

.post-overlay.juicer-feed .j-overlay-text { background: #fff; }

@media (max-width: 810px) {.j-overlay .j-overlay-content { width:60% !important }  }

.juicer-feed .j-stacker>* { border-top:0px; border-bottom:60px; border-left:30px solid #f1f1f0;  border-right:30px solid #f1f1f0; }
li.feed-item.pinterest.image-post.facticemagazine { margin-bottom:60px; }
</style>
```

Comment: put `li{margin-bottom:60px!important;}`

Comment: it works perfectly thank you misterrrrrr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a new class

```
.j-stacker .j-stack.galcolumn li.feed-item {
  margin-bottom: 60px
}
```

or you can try -

```
.feed-item {
    margin-bottom: 60px !important;
}
```

I hope it will works for you.